# App Centre Submission Detail Page Error

Tags: facebook

Have just received an email from Facebook with regards to the app details page for our app.

The email states:

> "General Changes Needed
>   Your app's Website with Facebook Login integration doesn't load."

I've searched the help forums, but I can't figure out what this means. Our app does load with facebook login and has been working for the last year. Does anyone know what this is referring to?